# Publically exposing .ipa and .mobileprovision files for beta testers

Tags: iphone

I'm currently sending my beta testers a link to a downloads section on my website, where they can download the *.mobileprovision and the latest *.ipa file.
I prefer doing this rather than sending large files over emails. But doing a bit of googling I couldn't find anyone else using the same method. So I got a bit worried that I might be doing something wrong.

The app is free so I no problems with others getting hold of the ipa.

Does anyone know of any apple terms and conditions that would prevent me from doing what I am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's AdHoc Distribution system is meant for this, and therefore it is legal. The fact that it is public is not a problem, since to install the app, your device must be an approved UDID in the .mobileprovision file. I publicly advertise my beta app, and it is perfectly fine.

Comment: He is not providing pre-release Apple Software to the public, only his *own* software..